# How to loop over a list of lists

Tags: python, list, for-loop

Recently I have come up with using a for loop to reform a list.

First, I did this:

```
list1 = [[1],[2],[3]]
list2 = []
for x in list1:
    list2.append(x)
print(list2)
```

And the output was:

```
[[1], [2], [3]]
```

Then, I tried：

```
list2 = []
for x in list1:
    list2.append(x[0])
```

And the output was:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Could someone please explain to me what `x[0]` does in this for loop? I thought this index would mean only taking the first element in a list.

Comment: To be specific, if I do x[0], should not it only take [1] into consideration as [1] is the first element in the list?

Comment: Instead of appending, print what x and x[0] are on each iteration and you should see something interesting.

Comment: `x[0]` _does_ mean only taking the first element of a list. You're looping over a bunch of lists, and taking the first element of each one.

Comment: the question's title is about list comprehensions and floats.. neither of which appear in your actual question

Comment: @Jason Please consider [accepting an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). If you find [no answer satisfactory](https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers), please consider editing your question(s) to provide more information. If you want to motivate answerers, please consider [starting a bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/). Accepting an answer shows your appreciation, rewards the author, provides incentive to others and informs everyone that your issue is resolved. You can always change your mind and accept a different answer later on.

Answer (score 1):

`x[0]` returns the item at index `0` of the list `x`, so by appending to a new list with `x[0]` in your `for` loop, you are appending the value within the sub-list rather than the sub-list itself, thereby achieving the effect you want, flattening the list.

Answer (score 1):

> Could you please tell what does "x[0]" do in this for loop; I thought this index would mean only taking the first element in a list.

`list1 = [[1],[2],[3]]` is not simply a list but a *list of lists*. Every element of `list1` is a list – albeit with only one sub-element. So you are effectively iterating over every list within your list `list1`, picking the first element at position `0` (which is all there is) and appending it to your new list `list2`.

Comment: @Jason Please consider [accepting an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). If you find [no answer satisfactory](https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers), please consider editing your question(s) to provide more information. If you want to motivate answerers, please consider [starting a bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/). Accepting an answer shows your appreciation, rewards the author, provides incentive to others and informs everyone that your issue is resolved. You can always change your mind and accept a different answer later on.

Answer (score 0):

When you go

```
for x in list1:
```

and print out `x` you'll get:

```
>[1]
>[2]
>[3]
```

Because each element in `list1` are still lists! The lists only have one element but they're still stored within a list. When you use `x[0]` you're telling Python you want to access the first element of each list, which is the number you want.

Also another thing you could do which would be faster than a `for` loop is to use list comprehension:

```
 list2 = [x[0] for x in list1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = [[1], [2], [3]]

for x in list1:
    list2.append(x[0])
```

Okay lets just look at what we are doing here:

`for x in list1`:

Well `x` in this loop will represent `[1], [2], [3]` which are list containing a certain number in the `0` position.

A little more perspective lets look at it like this:

`list1[0][0] = 1`

`list1[1][0] = 2`

`list1[2][0] = 3`

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating list containing list. 
e.g :

```
a = [[1], [2], [3]]
a[0] will contain list [1] #i.e it is containing list
a[1] will contain list [2] 
a[2] will contain list [3]
```

If you are want to access contents from list of list, you have to pass 2 indexes.
e.g :

```
a[0][0] will contain 1 #i.e it is containing element
a[1][0] will contain 2
a[2][0] will contain 3
```

You also can try `extend` keyword to achieve the same. The `extend()` method takes a single argument (a list) and adds it to the end.

```
list1 = [[1],[2],[3]]
list2 = []
for x in list1:
    list2.extend(x)
print(list2)
```